# In Chrome 51, how can I activate the Canvas Profiling Feature?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I activated devtools experiments in

```
about:flags
```

but nothing shows up in settings.

Has something changed or is the feature gone? thanks

Comment: if you downvote please tell at least why please. Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome DevTools [used to](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/) have a canvas profiler, as Garbee mentions, but unfortunately it was removed. (There have also been other Chrome extensions for general canvas inspection, but AFAIK none of them are still working/maintained)

Firefox has a general canvas debugger that's quite good: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-canvas-debugger-in-firefox-developer-tools/

[image]

Safari also added a canvas inspector that you can turn on.
[image]

Also note: there may be an extension for your framework (e.g. the three.js inspector).

Answer (score 2):

The experiment was removed. As far as I know it was never made stable, so that functionality is gone completely.